# Line break when you have more than one word in the menu

Tags: css, menu, line, break, words

I need to break the text in my vertical menu in 2 lines when there is more than one word in the "ul li" item.

In other words, I need to have a tag "br" between the two words in the element "li", but with css.

The images below make things clearer.

I have this
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz6D7.png)

I need this
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEoor.png)

Edit1: Live site: http://www.l9web.com.br/sites/test

Comment: What have you tried? What results did it produce?

Comment: Also, there's no way to do this with just CSS. You will need javascript or jQuery for example.

Comment: You don't have "Nucleo De Pesquisa" going to a new line or "Revistas E Periodicos" which are both more than 1 word. So what do you _really_ want? Maybe a max-width instead of a word count....

Comment: My template is responsive.

Comment: I want the text to be broken in two lines, when the phrase is ITEM MENU for example, I want it to stay ITEM in the first line and MENU in the second line, as if it had a BR between them

Comment: Live site: http://www.l9web.com.br/sites/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

On "ul li" we have to set:

white-space: pre-wap

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use word-spacing.

Try

```
ul li {
    word-spacing: 'parent-width'; // Percentages will not work 
}
```

Where 'parent width' is the width of the parent element. Maybe in the case the unordered list? That should give you one word per line. Best of luck!

I created a working pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYWBWW

If all you are going for is one word per line - set the word-spacing value to be larger than the width of the parent container. Any value will work:

```
ul li {
  word-spacing: 9999px; // very high value to force one word per line
}
```

Comment: @LucasCatani did you try to set `word-spacing: 100%`?

Comment: Yes, I tried to put the UL element with 200px size, and its LI elements with word-spacing: 200px. Did not work.

I tried to put UL with 200px size and LI with word-spacing: 100%. Nothing done.

Comment: Hmm do you have a URL or something where I can check it?

Comment: Try to set a really high word-spacing value like: `word-spacing: 9999px;` Check out this pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYWBWW

Comment: @LucasCatani Did you get a chance to try setting a high pixel value for word-spacing? I updated my answer and included a code pen.

Comment: Yes, i try. Look at live site @Radmation http://www.l9web.com.br/sites/test